Download PDF is not working in Safari browser only
Download PDF JavaScript function is not working only in Safari browser. However it is working fine for other browsers like Chrome, Edge etc. We tried the below code from the aura component. It doesn't seem to work.
    const linkSource = `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64}`;
    var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    var fileName = objId;
    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();

